# User model wont save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have the following code in my controller and cant figure out why the the user isnt being saved. It never gets into the action mailer and the user when I look in my database hasn't been updated.

```
def students
 if current_user.welcomed == false 
    current_user.welcomed = true
    if current_user.save
      UserMailer.welcome(current_user).deliver
    end  
 end 
end
```

any ideas? Thanks.

**Edit:**

Also I have verified that it does get into `if current_user.welcomed == false` but never into the save conditions

Comment: Maybe it's not saving. Did you check the logs? Also, I'd consider something like `unless current_user.welcomed` or something a bit more Ruby-esque.

Comment: @daveNewton I know its not saving `cant figure out why the the user isnt being saved.` I want to know why though.

Comment: replace `save` with `save!` and post errors from logs here

Comment: @nash thanks that revealed that the user was failing a validation that I wrote after that User had been originally created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @nash's suggsetion. Replacing `save` with `save!` revealed that the user was failing a validation that I wrote after that User had originally been created